# How to access Array data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, joomla

I have an SQL statement retrieving an array and I want to access that data.

My SQL (Joomla Syntax):

```
    $fields->select(array('a.virtuemart_product_id', 
         'a.virtuemart_custom_id', 'a.virtuemart_custom_id', 'v.value', 'r.intval'))
           ->from('#__virtuemart_product_customfields AS a')
           ->join('INNER', '#__virtuemart_product_custom_plg_param_ref AS r 
  ON (a.virtuemart_custom_id = r.virtuemart_custom_id 
  AND a.virtuemart_product_id = r.virtuemart_product_id)')
           ->join('INNER', '#__virtuemart_product_custom_plg_param_values 
  AS v ON (r.val = v.id)')
           ->where('a.virtuemart_product_id='.$vehicle_id)
           ->order('a.virtuemart_custom_id ASC');

    $db->setQuery($fields);
    // Load the results as a list of stdClass objects.
    $customs = $db->loadObjectList();
```

My Array output of `$customs` for one example

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [virtuemart_product_id] => 675
        [virtuemart_custom_id] => 38
        [value] => 2200 TD
        [intval] => 0
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [virtuemart_product_id] => 675
        [virtuemart_custom_id] => 39
        [value] => 6 Berth
        [intval] => 0
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [virtuemart_product_id] => 675
        [virtuemart_custom_id] => 40
        [value] => Coachbuilt
        [intval] => 0
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [virtuemart_product_id] => 675
        [virtuemart_custom_id] => 41
        [value] => 30990
        [intval] => 0
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [virtuemart_product_id] => 675
        [virtuemart_custom_id] => 42
        [value] => MX08 JVR
        [intval] => 0
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [virtuemart_product_id] => 675
        [virtuemart_custom_id] => 43
        [value] => Manual
        [intval] => 0
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [virtuemart_product_id] => 675
        [virtuemart_custom_id] => 44
        [value] => L23'7''
        [intval] => 0
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [virtuemart_product_id] => 675
        [virtuemart_custom_id] => 47
        [value] => 2008
        [intval] => 0
    )

[8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [virtuemart_product_id] => 675
        [virtuemart_custom_id] => 53
        [value] => Front Lounge
        [intval] => 0
    )

[9] => stdClass Object
    (
        [virtuemart_product_id] => 675
        [virtuemart_custom_id] => 54
        [value] => UNDER 3500kg
        [intval] => 0
    )
```

)

The above is within a `foreach`, simply selecting all products from the database. `$vehicle_id`

The ultimate goal is to output XML from the array by virtuemart_custom_id, so:

```
<Example> [value where virtuemart_custom_id = 1 ] </Example>
<ExampleTwo> [value where virtuemart_custom_id = 2] </ExampleTwo>
```

Problem: If I target $customs[1], the data might change if a row is empty.. bad? i.e. echo $customs[1]->value.

What's the best way I can achieve the above output whilst 'choosing' the `virtuemart_custom_id` I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($customs as $key=>$object){
      if($object->virtuemart_custom_id==1){
          //<Example> [value where virtuemart_custom_id = 1 ] </Example> 
          echo $object->value;
      }
}
```

In fact you can improve upon it and have a new array of all the values nicely like this

```
$values=array();
foreach($customs as $key=>$object){
   $values[$object->virtuemart_custom_id] = $object->value;
}
print_r($values);   // This will give you all values indexed on their custom ids
```

Answer (score 0):

use as

```
foreach($customs as $single){
      if( $single->virtuemart_custom_id==1){
          //<Example> [value where virtuemart_custom_id = 1 ] </Example> 
          echo $single->value;
      }
}
```